# PHP User Access

Tags: php, session, user-controls

im trying to create an access role script in which only the manager can edit a select box and assign an employee.

here is my code

**useraccess.php**

```
<?php    
    session_start();
    $useraccess = $_SESSION['userglobalaccess'] ;
    echo $useraccess ; // it will echo administrator or user just for me to see

    if ($useraccess=='administrator')
        {
           $_SESSION['employeeincharge'] ='';
        }

    else
        {
            $_SESSION['employeeincharge'] ='disable';
        }      
 ?>
```

in my html have select with this property

**addrecord.html**

```
<select name="test" id="test1">
    <option  <?php echo $_SESSION['employeeincharge']; ?> value="John">John</option>
    <option  <?php echo $_SESSION['employeeincharge']; ?> value="Jeff">Jeff</option>
    <option  <?php echo $_SESSION['employeeincharge']; ?> value="Nikko">Nikko</option>
</select>
```

when im looking at page view source it will say it is has disable property. but yet it is not disabled and i can select in option eve if im only have user access.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `disable` into `disabled`

[w3 reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp)

Comment: fu.... men thanks! i think i need a coffee. i thinking so much that i can't check that simple mistake hahaha. thanks! appreciate your help!